# Filter results with ajax and modify URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, filter

I'm trying to build a filter feature for a website I am currently building in Laravel, that will enable the customer to filter a product down by it's attributes.

At the moment, the URL to filter products is `/filter?size=1,2,3&construction=102,204&brand=4,37`.

What I'd like to be able to do, is change the URL based on chosen filters and refresh the results without re-loading the page.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is AO.com's filtering: http://ao.com/l/washing_machines-free_standing/1-9/1/#!/washing_machines-bosch-free_standing-priced_350_to_450-7kgandmore/1-6-9-23-39/1/

I've searched a lot on the internet to try and find the best way to go about it, but I can't seem to find a definitive method.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that'll be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of AO filter is a select option, e.g: Most popular.

With Jquery/AJAX you can filter:

```
$('select[name="yourSelectCategory"]').change(function(){
   var selected = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: "yourPostRoute",
       data: {userSelected: selected},
       //You can also add dataType: "json" if you want to return json data
       // and cache: false,
       success: function(html){
       //Use the data

      $('.filterResultContainer').load('/yourDataResultView');
}
});
});
```

Controller:

```
$data = Input::get('userSelected');
//Query the DB where category = $data or category like $data
//Pass the result data to yourDataResultView.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Michel. I noticed AO have got a hashbang in their URL, how would that fit into your answer?

Comment: The hashbang is added to the URL. You can decide to add either before calling the ajax method or after the result. And I think it's encrypted/hashed so that will depend on the hashing approach you might decide to use